# .net multilingual cms

Tags: .net, content-management-system, multilingual

I am planning a simple, dual-language website and I'd like to use a .net based cms but I can't find anything suitable.

I have experience with dotnetnuke and sharepoint but neither fits the bill - dotnetnuke does not do dynamic site elements multi-lingually & sharepoint is a monster PITA no matter what angle you look at it :).

I am on the verge of choosing Joomla! & Joom!Fish. They fit the bill nicely, with one exception: I would like to create some cms plug-ins and I would much prefer to write them in .net.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There is the [N2 CMS](http://n2cms.com/), which is pretty good. Also have a look at [cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/)?  I have worked with it to try out for clients and it looks really good.

I would look to them as a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Kentico](http://www.kentico.com/) is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com). It is proprietary, but supports multilingual sites and is very, very extensible. .NET-based so you can basically fine-tune it for your needs, or write anything custom that is not coming out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Ektron CMS400.net](http://www.ektron.com) -- it's an excellent CMS with great built-in translation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with
@Danimal
ektron is very good. It's not free, but you definitely get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

[BlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net) is pretty good for a blogging platform with good multi-lingual support.

Answer (score 0):

1 more vote for Umbraco.
Depends on what you are used to, but is one of the nicest CMS I've used, and have found it pretty easy to add my own user controls to it.
Apparently supports multi languages, but I have never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for umbraco. It has never ever limited me in any way. It does have a learning curve, but once you get to know the basics of the system, you'll be amazed what things can be done in a short period of time. Also, great supporting community!

Answer (score 0):

[Webnodes CMS](http://www.webnodes.com) supports multiple languages, and you don't need to know XSLT.. The templates are standard aspx pages..

You define content types in the content definitions module, and strongly typed classes are created based on those content types. This gives you strongly typed collections, and compile time error checking, as well as Intellisense for all properties on a content object(called a node). Since the system also has a built-in ORM, you never have to write a line of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Umbraco DOES NOT support 1:1 or "tabbed" translations. I would never recommend it as an i18n solution.

Answer (score -1):

For .NET, assuming you're comfortable with XSLT, Umbraco - [www.umbraco.org](http://www.umbraco.org)

The XSLT qualification is important because that's the basis of the template (for content) system so whilst the end users have no requirement to use XSLT those defining the templates will.

---

Edit:

As we roll towards the end of 2011 there is now an alternative to XSLT, support for the Razor engine is being added to Umbraco and its fair to say that Razor is probably a bit less challenging than XSLT (much as I continute to be impressed by what one can do with XSLT, it does need a different mindset).

Comment: Who is it that has a grudge against umbraco? Could you at least bother to comment to say why you regard what is *clearly* a useful answer as bad?

Comment: Is an obvious anti umbraco pattern going on here, but not enough cajones to say why.

Comment: And another random downvote? Not helpful without explanation.

Answer (score -1):

+1 for Umbraco as a great CMS.  As far as multilingual support though, I'm in the same boat as seanb.  I know it supports it, but I've never dealt with it myself.